# Use named range to loop through sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range compiled of 30 string values. Each of the string values is also used as the name of a sheet. I was wondering if it would be possible to loop through each string in the range to edit it's respective sheet. I've gone through some trial and error but am still stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NamedRanges()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Variant

rng = Sheets("Teams").Range("TeamList_Full")

For Each ws In rng
    ws.Range("A36").Value2 = 2
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You have it backwards? Wouldn't it be for each e in rng/sheets(e).range("A35")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Sub NamedRanges()

    Dim c As Range
    
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Teams").Range("TeamList_Full").Cells
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(c.Value).Range("A36").Value2 = 2
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just had to change "Next ws" to "Next c".

Comment: @Nick - or you can just use `Next` by itself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be targeting the *same* cell on each sheet, you can also achieve your aim by avoiding a loop

```
Sub NamedRanges()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Teams").Range("TeamList_Full")
    Set sh = Worksheets(rng.Cells(1).Value2)
    sh.Range("A36").Value2 = 2
    Worksheets(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value2)).FillAcrossSheets sh.Range("A36")
End Sub
```